# How to add this jQuery script to my Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to load external data for my website and it uses jQuery. Well I know absolutely nothing about jQuery so I got a script delivered and need to paste this somewhere to make Wordpress use it . Now do I know if Wordpress already has jQuery running? I guess not as I started out blank.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/Energievergelijker/style.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="//developers.affiliateprogramma.eu/Energievergelijker/general.js"></script> 
<div class="daisyconEnergyComparator" 
    data-daisyconEnergyMediaID="279942" 
    data-daisyconEnergySubID="" 
    data-business="false" 
    data-daisyconEnergyAmount="10" 
    data-daisyconEnergyActionPackets="all"       
    data-daisyconEnergyPackets="all" 
    data-daisyconEnergyCompanies="all" 
    data-daisyconEnergyDuration="all" 
    data-daisyconEnergyDuurzaam="all" 
    data-daisyconEnergyView="all" 
    data-daisyconEnergyUrl="" 
    data-daisyconEnergyShowActionTable="true" 
    data-daisyconEnergyHouse="Appartement" 
    data-daisyconEnergyPersons="Enkel" 
    data-daisyconEnergySave="1" 
    data-daisyconEnergyUrl="" 
    data-daisyconEnergyMeter="enkel" 
    data-daisyconEnergyBaseColor="3498DB" 
    data-daisyconEnergyActionColor="FF8201" >
    <div class="daisyconEnergyFilters"></div>
    <div class="daisyconEnergyTableContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggested an edit that makes your code visible. You should have a look at the result before posting anything. You can see it under the box where you are typing stuff. Just posting the code won't help, as the html is not interpreted as text that is to be displayed, but as html that is supposed to be embedded. Therefore it's invisible. And a line with a single dash makes the paragraph before it a header, which is why your text was really big and bold. Nobody can answer your question if they can't even read it!

Comment: It seems you need to add postcode or similar to the URL to get anything

Comment: Folks: When a person with 1 rep posts a question with **CODE:** and no code, assume he did not yet figure out how to format it and give it 5 minutes before voting it to hell.

Comment: Thanks. First visit, Looked fine when typed, but I learn. Rather have an helping answer the negatives.

Comment: I just tested the script it works from a webserver if you add ?postcode=1234AA (change to an actual Dutch postcode). Wordpress normally includes jQuery - view-source of your page and search ".js" if you see jQuery then you do not have to add the line with 1.8.3. Then make sure there are no console errors - press F12 and look at the console. If errors post them in your question.

Comment: Why is question marked by the [`add`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/add/info) tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just GO to `function.php` and enqueue your script using `wp_enqueue_script()` with the dependency of `jquery`. Read More at [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).